# JQuery mobile elements not reflowing from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a simple use case where I am creating a form for customers to update their profile information. I am using jquery mobile.
So I have a few fields like email telephone number.
The only problem is that my telephone number is split into 3 fields Code Code, Area code and number. i have created 3 text fields to capture each of these items using the Jquery Mobile Grid, the only problem beign when i switch from Portrait mode to landscape of my device the elements do not reflow .
As you can see from the screen shots below the telephone number fields do not reflow like the email an title fields.
See attached screen shots.
[image]

[image]

The source code for this is

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
         <h3>
            Header
        </h3>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label>Telephone number</label>
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <input name="" id="textinput4" placeholder="area code" value="" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <input name="" id="textinput5" placeholder="c code" value="" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <input name="" id="textinput6" placeholder="number" value="" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textinput1">Email</label>
            <input name="" id="textinput1" placeholder="" value="" type="email">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textinput8">Title</label>
            <input name="" id="textinput8" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h3>
            Footer
        </h3>

    </div>
</div>
```

The JS fiddle link for this is 
http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddle_one/mBBYf/

Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Sorry in case you are not able to see the screen shot, just expan and collapse the output on the fiddle and you will understand what i mean.

Comment: if you remove `<div data-role="fieldcontain">` they reflow as they should with little CSS tuning. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dHabx/

Answer (score 0):

You must add the meta tags needed for jquery mobile for make it responsive and neat.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html> 
  <head> 
<title>My Page</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

  </head>
```

Add this to the top of your html. The meta tag with device width and initial scale is more important

----  EDIT -----

You need to close the header before fieldcontain div and start data-role="content" div like this

http://jsfiddle.net/mBBYf/1/

Comment: Hi manu, thank you for your input, but this has already been added but it still does not work

Comment: I have edited it p[lease check. You didnt close the header div that's why the problem. Please check the updated fiddle

Comment: Hi Manu, i think you havent understood my requirement as yet,lets take 2 fields the telephone number and the email. When i reduce the size of the page the email label is above the text field. And when i increase the width the email and text fields are on the same line. This does not happen for the telephone fields, the telephone label always remains on top of the 3 text fields, i.e basically a  responsive design where form elements are labels reflow based on width of the viewport

Answer (score 0):

add the class "ui-responsive" after the ui-grid-b. This will make all of those text elements to stack on top of each other